# Invalid Id while trying to insert custom object

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

I have a custom object that I could insert in the past, but for some reason it has stopped working and I can't seem to find the issue.

I have a contact relationship object that I am trying to insert like this:

```
Contact_Relationship__c newConRel = new Contact_Relationship__c(
                        RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact_Relationship__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Consumer_Contact').getRecordTypeId(),
                        Relationship__c = optionMap.containskey(xyz.relationship)?optionMap.get(xyz.relationship):null,
                        Role__c = xyz.role,
                        abctext__c = xyz.abcText,
                        Engage__c = engagementId,
                        Contact_To__c = contactId,
                        isVerified__c = true
                    );

insert newConRel;
```

I am getting 'Invalid id: at line 1

Since this is an insert, I don't have the id value. How to resolve this please ?

Comment: Why do you have a space in `Consumer `?  Record type names won't have a trailing space, so your statement won't return a record type.

Comment: its typo, update the post.

Comment: You should really use `DeveloperName`, not `Name`.

Comment: could it be an invalid relationship__c (if that is a lookup field), engagementId or contactId?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I update it to DeveloperName, still getting the same error.

Comment: @cropredy, thanks for the quick find, yes, I was passing string in contactId and hence failed. got it fixed. Thanks much !

Comment: @Sam Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it resolved your question

Answer (score 1):

The "invalid id" error can occur if any of the object's lookup fields are not recognizable Id fields:

- RecordtypeId (looks Ok)
- contactId
- engagementId

Check your method to ensure the latter two are valid ids coming from soql, sosl or DML inserts